# One vs Two Omnidirectional Antenna - Transmitter

Tags: rf, antenna, transmitter

I am looking for the best line of sight range for a 5.8GHz video transmitter on an aircraft.  Options are one or two omnidirectional transmitting antennas.  Max transmitting power will go to a single antenna setup, as I am not expecting physical obstacles - is it reasonable to assume the single antenna would provide the best range?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'd only use two antennas on the transmit side of you had two transmitters on different frequencies. There's no other case in which two is better than one. On the receive side you will often use two, connected to separate receivers or a beamforming receiver.

Answer (score 0):

> is it reasonable to assume the single antenna would provide the best range?

No. You're forgetting that you actually increase the effective area with more antennas.

Generally, if you're really after range, you'd try to have a system with multiple antennas and beamforming (which is a special case of MIMO).

Comment: Right.  But with 2 (or more) antennas, you're going have some beam forming.  Which means the combined pattern of the two antennas is not omni-directional anymore.

Comment: @SteveSh which is fine, because rarely need you communicate with a drone that's below the operator